# AWS Cognito - invite user from browser application (adminCreateUser)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In AWS cognito there is an option in admin panel to create a new user by sending him an invitation with temporary password. It works good, but I need to implement exactly the same feature inside my application (react spa).

I am using aws-amplify-js but I can't see there any method which do that. In aws-sdk documentation I see adminCreateUser what is a function I need, but it requires developer credentials so I suppose I shouldn't use it in browser.

Any ideas how to implement this feature in proper way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lambda and API endpoint to send the invitation. Of course, you should protect the API endpoint access using custom authorization to prevent non-authorized users to call this endpoint.

Visit the following for more info about the SDK:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminCreateUser-property